# sed replace $_REQUEST["hello"] with functionName('hello')

Tags: arrays, variables, replace, sed

in my old php app im still requesting parameters with $_REQUEST,
now i have a function which does some checks before returning.

So i want all variables like $_REQUEST["hello"] replace with my function so i have something like _request('hello')

i tried the following sed command, but it doesnt find my $_REQUEST variables.

```
sed 's/$_REQUEST\["(.*)"\]/_request('\1')/g'
```

I tried different things like escaping the $ char or changing the regex (.*), but it does not work. What is wrong on this one?

I will use this command to save time changing all my $_REQUEST vars into the function call.

Comment: It's the single quotes around \1 that are messing you up - the first one breaks out of the sed command and back to shell so it's shell that sees the \1, not sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ cat file
sed replace $_REQUEST["hello"] with functionName('hello')

$ sed 's/\$_REQUEST\["\([^"]*\)"\]/_request('\''\1'\'')/g' file
sed replace _request('hello') with functionName('hello')
```

You need to use '\'' because the ' breaks you back into shell so then you need to provide a literal ' in shell followed by another ' to get back into sed. I also changed .* to [^"]* so it'll stop at the end of your string rather than the last " on the line.